# Groovy InputStream reading closure hanging

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to make a Java program more "Groovy".  The java code reads an InputStream like so:

```
static int myFunction(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    int b=is.read();
    if (b==0) return b;
    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
    int c;
    boolean done = false;
    while(!done) {
        c=is.read();
        sb.append((char)c);
        if(c == '\n') {
           done=true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    if (b == 1) throw new IOException("blah");
    return b;
}
```

My Groovy version looks like this:

```
def myFunction(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    int b=is.read()
    if (b==0) return b
    def reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))
    reader.eachLine { println(it) } 
    println("DONE")
    if (b == 1) throw new IOException("blah")
    return b
}
```

It prints the contents of the stream and then just hangs as if it's trying to read more.  It never prints "DONE" (added for debugging).  Next I tried it using is.eachByte and passing a closure with an explicit "if (c == '\n') return" but I found that return inside a closure acts more like a continue and doesn't actually break out of the closure.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
reader.eachLine { println(it) }
```

Can you try

```
println reader.readLine()
```

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.  Any idea why the closure didn't return in my code?

Comment: `eachLine` will loop forever reading each line in turn, and there's no way of breaking out of a closure

Comment: Even if there are no more lines?  What is the point of that?  Would you only use it in cases where you wanted an infinite loop?

Comment: I have a similar need for an inputStream which comes from a socket.  Unfortunately, it has no readLine() equivalent, which is exactly what I need.  I can only eachLine{}, or readLines(), or getText(). Each if these is sub-optimal.  What would you suggest in that case?

Comment: My previous question is invalid. I did not read the original post closely, and did not see that it was wrapped in a BufferedReader. I also had it confused with another post regarding fileinputstream. I will wrap my inputstream in a bufferedreader.